# Can you build a monowheel in Little Big Planet?

Tags: little-big-planet

I tried many times to build a monowheel in Little Big Planet, but failed, as I couldn’t get gravity working correctly. No matter what I did, it ended up being Sackboy rotating rapidly rather than the wheel moving.

[image]